# PostgreSQL 9.5: Convert intervals INTO milliseconds

Tags: postgresql

I have the following two dates which is in the form of varchar(50).

Date1: `2016-11-24 12:38:29.123`

Date2: `2016-04-22 11:44:55`

First date that is `Date1` contains milliseconds and `Date2` contains till seconds.
So i did casting to get up to seconds from both dates.

Using:

```
SELECT ('2016-11-24 12:38:29.123'::timestamp(0) - '2016-04-22 11:44:55'::timestamp(0));
```

**Output**:

`216 days 00:53:34`

**Note**: Now i want to convert `216 days 00:53:34` into milliseconds.

## My try:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MILLISECONDS FROM(CAST('2016-11-24 12:38:29.123' AS timestamp(0)) - CAST('2016-04-22 11:44:55' AS timestamp(0))));
```

**Output**:

`34000`

**Problem**: `34000` is not the exact milliseconds of `216 days 00:53:34`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are looking for `epoch` which returns the number of seconds stored in the interval.

```
SELECT extract(epoch from timestamp '2016-11-24 12:38:29.123' - timestamp '2016-04-22 11:44:55');
```

returns: 18665614